# Efficient Creation and Storage of Contour Lines from a 3D Triangular Mesh

Tags: data-structures, 3d, contour

I need to generate multiple contours in a specified range from a 3D Triangular Mesh. To simply generate points at height specified by the z coordinate I create a plane vec4(0,0,1,z) then loop through all the triangles in the mesh,eliminate a number of triangles by checking height against individual AABB and perform line-plane intersection on each edge of the triangle.This works and returns a set of points having z = height including duplicate points.
For dense meshes the number of points is quite large.
Regarding storage, I use a binary tree to keep track height z and the points are stored using a simple vector.

How do I improve this naive implementation ?
What data structure can be used to store set of points corresponding to a specific height z?

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is (what you want to achieve), how you solved it and what the problem with the solution is? I.e. what do you mean "contours"? Why and how do you "simply create points"? Why do you eliminate triangles? What is the "height" in "z=height"? What is the problem with storing points in a vector? Etc. 
Maybe an illustration would help.

Comment: If you want to find all triangles that intersect with a plane, how about creating AABBs for all triangles, put them in an index and then query for all AABBs that intersect with your plane?

Comment: Ahh great !!! That could definitely work. About the problem, I need to fetch a set of points from a 3D mesh having z coordinate  = something for 3D printing. I was wondering if there was any other data structure I could use for storing those points  but  any I don't require to perform any others operations (like querying individual points)  a simple vector works.